# GWT compile - why still 5 permutations after only having one user.agent option?

Tags: gwt, compilation

Trying to speed up gwt compile, did the following:

```
 <module rename-to=xxxx>
  <inherits name='com.yyy.basemodule>
  <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
   <extend-property name='locale' values='en' />
 </module>
```

But when compiling, expecting only permutation, still saying:

"Compiling 5 permutations"

Any clue?

Comment: Is the tag `<inherits name='com.yyy.basemodule>` open by c&p mistake? If not, that might be the problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `<set-property name="locale" value="default"/>` instead of the extend-property tag.